# Fourier transform of linear combination of chracteritic functions preserves $L^2$ norm

Tags: lp-spaces, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

Let $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx$ be the Fourier transform of a function $f\in L^1$. I'm trying to prove that if $f$ is a linear combination of characteristic function of compacts interval, then $||\hat{f}||_{L^2}=||f||_{L^2}$. I know this is valid for more functions, but the exercise asks us to calculate that. I've managed to show this is true when $f(x)=\lambda\cdot\chi_{[a,b]}(x)$, where $\chi_{[a,b]}(x)$ is the characteristic/indicator function of the interval $[a,b]$, but I'm having trouble when $f$ is a linear combination with more than one term, since we must square the absolute value of $f$ in the $L^2$ norm. Any tips?
Here's what I got so far:
Suppose $f = \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\chi_{[a_j,b_j]}$. We can assume the intervals are disjoint. Then $||f||_{L^2} = \sqrt{\sum|\lambda_j|^2(b_j-a_j)}$

While,
$$ \int|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2d\xi = \sum_{j=1}^n|\lambda_j|^2\int|\mathcal{{F}(\chi_{[a_j,b_j]}})|^2+2\sum_{j\neq i}\lambda_j\lambda_i\int\Re(\mathcal{{F}(\chi_{[a_j,b_j]}})\overline{\mathcal{{F}(\chi_{[a_i,b_i]}}))}$$
Where $\mathcal{F}(f)=\hat{f}.$ But
$$\mathcal{{F}(\chi_{[a_j,b_j]}}) = \frac{e^{-2\pi i\xi a_j}-e^{-2\pi i\xi b_j}}{2\pi i\xi}$$

Is the last term zero? I'm having trouble calculating this integral, it doesn't seem to converge even. Notice the exercise becomes trivial if I assume $\langle f,g\rangle = \langle \hat{f},\hat{g}\rangle$, as some users suggested, so I believe I can't use that.

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem holds on both sides so you can try writing $f$ as a linear combinations of characteristic functions of *disjoint* intervals (so that those functions are orthogonal).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's easy to show that the characteristic functions are orthogonal, but how do I show that their Fourier transform is also?

Answer (score 1):

You can always assume that characteristic functions have disjoint support - if not then you just split two characteristic functions, say of sets $A$ and $B$ into sum of three sets $A-B$, $B-A$ and $A\cap B$. Once you have this note that second power of linear combinations is the sum on second powers i.e. products of two characteristics functions is $0$ (since they have disjoint support). Now, just use your prove for a single characteristic function.

Comment: This works for calculating $||f||_{L^2}$, but how do I deal with $||\hat{f}||_{L^2}$?

Comment: The same, i.e. Fourier transformation preserves scalar product, i.e. orthogonal functions are mapped into orthogonal.

Comment: Yeah, I know it preserves a scalar product, but this exercise idea is to prove exactly that, so I think I'm not supposed to assume that

Comment: Are you saying you have to proof Fubini's Theorem as a part of this exercise?

Comment: How does that follow from Fubini's Theorem? I don't know a simple proof of that fact.